# Particle trail path in geometry nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'd like to create a particle trail path that follows a certain object in geometry nodes. Let's say each trail path has 15 points. In code I know I'd store the position of each point for the next iteration, shift the list of positions by one, discard the last position and create new position for the first point based on position of geometry it follows. How would one go about this with geometry nodes?

[image]

I know it's possible to store the last position as an attribute of each point. What I am not sure is how I'd keep shifting the list of attributes by one whenever the original geometry moves (or whether it is even possible). I've seen similar effect with predrawn path it follows (that one is quite easy to do) but I'd like a solution that doesn't need it.

Comment: My tip: Don't try this with *Geometry Nodes*. You have no way to read the data of other frames, unless you would precalculate the whole movement. There are solutions, but I would rather call them a *hack*. Maybe use *Animation Nodes* instead.

Comment: The geometry is made in GN and I'd like it to stay procedural. Precalculation of the whole movement is not different from predrawing the followed path.

Comment: and who said that animation nodes isn't procedural?

Comment: No one. I know animation nodes are procedural. But I want the geometry to stay procedural. Not to apply the modifier and after that animate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **only** in the blender simulation branch (or by using the buffer hack).

If you are willing to use that branch then this is how you shift the points attributes:
The easiest way is to use a curve, which has a topology node called *offset point in curve*; set the offset to -1. Using the *index* output of this node as the *index* input of the *field at index* node and the previous frame's position as the attribute, then use a switch (set to *vector*) with the *is valid offset* as the switch, the value output of the *field at index* as *true*, and the current position of the mover as *false*. this result should be stored as the next previous position (with store named attribut node) and set as the current position (with set position node.

this should all be wrapped in a simulation node loop.